# Groupping and concat with parent and child pardigma in an array php

Tags: php, arrays, excel

Basically I am using phpexcel.

I have 3 column in those excel be to gorupping it hierarichal.

Column : delivery_order_tli_id is parent. Column : delivery_order_hanwa_id is child of parent. COlumn : coil_ids is concatenate based child of parent.

This is the data.
In this excel, the data like this :

```
delivery_order_tli_id   delivery_order_hanwa_id     coil_id
        1                       1                     108
        1                       1                     114
        1                       1                     116
        1                       1                     120
        1                       1                     123
        1                       1                     130
        1                       1                     163
        2                       1                     113
        2                       1                     115
        2                       1                     117
        2                       1                     119
        2                       1                     129
        2                       1                     131
        2                       1                     161
        3                       3                     171
        3                       221                   2880
        3                       221                   2881
        3                       221                   2887
        3                       221                   2889
        3                       221                   2890
        4                       4                     236
        4                       4                     237
        4                       4                     238
        4                       4                     239
        4                       4                     244
        4                       4                     245
        4                       5                     246
        4                       4                     253
```

So,

```
$activeSheetData = $objPhpExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);
```

I successfully load those column into array.

I nedd format like this.

```
delivery_order_tli_id   delivery_order_hanwa_id                     coil_ids
            1                       1                   108, 114, 116, 120, 123, 130, 163
            2                       1                   113, 115, 117, 119, 129, 131, 161
            3                       3                   171
            3                       221                 2880, 2881, 2887, 2889,2890
            4                       4                   236, 237,238,239, 244, 245, 253
            4                       5                   246
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
$result = array();
foreach ($activeSheetData as $data) {
    if (isset($result[$data['delivery_order_tli_id'] . $data['delivery_order_hanwa_id']])) {
        $result[$data['delivery_order_tli_id'] . $data['delivery_order_hanwa_id']]['coil_id'][] = $data['coil_id'];
        $result[$data['delivery_order_tli_id'] . $data['delivery_order_hanwa_id']]['coil_id_csv'] = join(',', $result[$data['delivery_order_tli_id'] . $data['delivery_order_hanwa_id']]['coil_id']);
    } else {
        $result[$data['delivery_order_tli_id'] . $data['delivery_order_hanwa_id']] = array(
            'delivery_order_tli_id' => $data['delivery_order_tli_id'],
            'delivery_order_hanwa_id' => $data['delivery_order_hanwa_id'],
            'coil_id' => array($data['coil_id']),
            'coil_id_csv' => $data['coil_id']
        );
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0c66b51773c7b7f4162472e17d44bf873a6c0a4e)